# Create a script which disables a Windows Account on a target host. Only Admin can execute this action

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to create a PowerShell script which will disable the windows account, the target host name will be provided as an argument. Only admin should be able to execute this task.

This is what I have tried. Could someone please tell me if this approach is right or is there any better way to do this.

```
    param( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $TargetHost ,
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [String] $TargetUserName ,
       [String] $User , 
       [String] $Password)

# Set up a trap to properly exit on terminating exceptions
trap [Exception] {
    write-error $("TRAPPED: " + $_)
    exit 1
    }

function DeactivateAccount($TargetHost , $TargetUserName ,$User , $Password){

    $TargetHost = $TargetHost #Target Host on which windows account deactivation will be done.
    $TargetUserName = $TargetUserName   #User Name of Target.
    $Domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain() #Domain name of the localhost.
    $localHost = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
    $localIP = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("$localHost")

    #if TargetHost and LocalHost are same.
    if($localHost -like $TargetHost -OR $localIP -like $TargetHost) {

        if($Domain -eq [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()){
            $process = net user $TargetUsername /domain /active:no #Performs the operation on the domain controller in the computer's primary domain.
        } else {
            $process = net user $TargetUsername /active:no
        }
        Write-host " $TargetUsername account deactivated "
    }

    #If TargetHost is remote Host.
    else {
        $User = $User #Creds to perform admin function.
        $Password = $Password
        $SecurePassword = new-Object System.Security.SecureString #Convert password into secure string.
        $Password.ToCharArray() | % { $SecurePassword.AppendChar($_) }
        $Cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "$User",$securePassword

        $newSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName "$TargetHost" -credential $Cred #Used PSSession for persistent connection and credentials to Specify a user account that has permission to perform this action.

        $export_username =  Invoke-Command -Session $newSession -ScriptBlock {$username=args[1]} # Invoke-Command command uses the Session parameter(here newSession) to run the commands in same session.
        if($Domain -eq [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()){
                $process =  Invoke-Command -Session $newSession -ScriptBlock {net user $username /domain /active:no}
            } else {
                $process =  Invoke-Command -Session $newSession -ScriptBlock {net user $username /active:no}
            }
        Write-host " $TargetUsername account deactivated "
        Remove-PSSession $newSession # Closes Windows PowerShell sessions.
        }

    if(-not $?) { # Returns true if last command was successful.
        Write-Error "Windows Deactivation Failed!!"
        exit 1
    }
}

DeactivateAccount($TargetHost , $TargetUserName ,$User , $Password)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

Your meant to show some code to show you tried but since you're new to Powershell I'll let that slide :)

Is it a local windows account you are trying to disable or an AD one?  For the purpose of this I'll assume local.

Grab this module: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/PowerShell-Module-to-255637a3

The dude basically made a module for exactly what you want to do :)

Note: If you have Powershell 5.1+ you won't need the module they added new cmdlets to do this natively.

Credential-wise I wouldn't worry, Powershell can't bypass windows security, it will execute with the permissions of the user that ran the script unless your script specifically gives credentials for another user in the commands.

Let me know how you get on.